# Maximum number of conditions in Firebase Audience

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm building a Firebase Audience where I enum a number of particular android device models, but when I try so save it, I have the following error message:

```
You have exceeded the maximum number of conditions allowed.
One of your condition groups has more than the maximum number of conditions.
```

There are about 40 conditions in one of the groups, but I can't find exact maximum number of conditions allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found, there are only 10 conditions allowed. Here is the example:

[image: Here is the example]

Answer (score 2):

Firebase allows a maximum of 10 conditions for an Audience

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).